# Spam texts to run up a person's bill

Tags: halacha, technology, torts-damages

Many cell phone plans allot a person a certain number of texts each month and charge for every text over that limit. This is for both texts sent and received.

Now, phone calls can be denied, but texts cannot.

Let's say a person (Reuven) sends his friend (Shimon) a bunch of spam texts, which ultimately causes Shimon to go over his texting limit. Let's also assume that Reuven knows what plan Shimon has and deliberately sends him enough texts to cause him to go over.

Can Shimon refer the overage to Reuven to pay, as it was because Reuven sent the texts that Shimon was sent the bill?

Issues to consider: gerama, hezik she'eino nikar, and is this even considered nezek to begin with. Not to the exclusion of others I haven't thought of.

Comment: You can disable all texts. Just call your service provider

Comment: Most plans allow texts from specific numbers to be blocked. The question would be if someone sends sufficient texts to cause the runover before the number can be blocked (such as over shabbos).

Comment: The biggest issue you haven't mentioned would be if the sender intentionally did this in order to have the receiver accrue extra costs. Kavanaso lihazik by a gramma is what this would then be. Yesh ladon if stam spam qualifies.

Comment: Your description sounds in line with what @user6591 mentioned. It seems that Reuven caused intentional damage. User6591, if you would, please explain the Hebrew (transliterated) terminology.

Comment: "Spam" is a vague term. I think every user understands that they will be receiving spam texts, inevitably. In NY state, I think Senator Schumer is trying  to pass a law to prevent this. But, until that happens, it becomes the user's responsibility to block the spam texts (I understand that some carriers do allow receiving specific text users or blocking numbers.) Otherwise, since by definition spam is "built in" to the contract, it seems that you automatically agree to receiving unlimited texts from anyone.

Comment: @DanF Gramma is hard to succinctly translate, but I'll go with residual or indirect harm. Kavanaso Lihazik is intention to harm, for which even gramma would be chayav. Another example is writing a check that bounces and now the depositor has to pay a fee. That fee is a gramma as far as I've been told by members of the beis din I asked. So the one who wrote it out would not have to pay. If the one who wrote it knew they didn't have funds in the account that would be a gramma with intention to cause indirect harm, which would then be chayav.

Comment: Before texts to cell phones cost people money, faxes did (not a provider charge there, but paper and ink), which people sometimes used as a weapon.  (I remember somebody doing that to the green-card spammers, way back when spam was new.)  Perhaps there is prior work there.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yeah, faxes were before my time, but I can definitely imagine that someone would have written about that.

Comment: It doesn't sound like Reuven can really be described as a "friend" of Shimon if he's doing that sort of stuff to him...unless they'll both think it's some kind of joke, and they've been doing them to each other for a while. "Ha ha, I ran your phone bill up!"  "Ha ha, I got your mortgage application cancelled!"   "Ha ha, I left you in the middle of Gaza with a huge "Chabad Outreach Program Director" sign!"  Not my definition of a "friendly" friendship.

Comment: @Gary See Shemos 21:14: וְכִֽי־יָזִ֥ד אִ֛ישׁ עַל־רֵעֵ֖הוּ לְהָרְג֣וֹ בְעָרְמָ֑ה מֵעִ֣ם מִזְבְּחִ֔י תִּקָּחֶ֖נּוּ לָמֽוּת׃ (ס) - premeditated murder against "one's friend."

Comment: @DonielF - there's a long way between premeditated murder and running a cell phone bill up...

Comment: @Gary If even by premeditated murder you can call the victim his friend, surely you can do so here. There is no other analogy being made other than the use of the word "friend."

Comment: Whether its assur or not, its definetly a bad midda.